# Twilio configure video peer to peer, no recording and recording audio with low sample rate?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to configure Twilio to record audio only, but with:

- mono
- Sample rate: 8Khz
- Bitrate: 24 KBps

I know that I can define a RecordFilter to include or exclude audio/video ( for instance:

```
"rules": [
    {
      "type": "include",
      "kind": "audio"
    }
```

But how I can configure that video be managed as "peer to peer" ?

And also, How I can configure sample rate, mono and bitrate for the audio track?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Twilio Video can only record group rooms, not peer to peer.

Comment: I want to record only audio, therefore you know if is possible to record audio only and  at the same time use video peer to peer? (without video recording)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a connection with Twilio Video, you can choose to connect peer to peer or via a group room. You cannot mix the two.

Twilio can only record when you are using a room, it can't when you are using peer to peer because the media doesn't go through Twilio's servers. Twilio can only record when you connect through a group room.

Comment: ok, Thanks philnash, regarding to the audio configuration (mono/stereo, sample rate...), do you know if it´s possible to do?

Comment: Depends on browser support, but when you request access to the microphone, you can set constraints. In some browsers you can request [`sampleRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/sampleRate), [`channelCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/channelCount) (choose 1 channel for mono) and [`sampleSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/sampleSize) to control the bit depth.